# using powershell how to display the service applications db names?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

Using power shell how to display the service applications data base names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-SPDatabase | where {$_.Type -notcontains "Content Database" -and $_.Type -notcontains "Configuration Database"} | sort Type | format-table –autosize
```